# How to get length of array if poses from nav_msgs/Path.msg

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to  use the message type nav_msgs/Path.msg. according to the wiki it is an array of poses that are used to plan a path but it  I'm unable to get the msg in array form.  I need to get the length of the array for my purposes which is why I'm asking. How do I go about that?
right now I just have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Path
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
import numpy as np

def callback(msg):
    print("list: ", msg)

rospy.init_node("tester_3")
rospy.Subscriber("/move_base/NavfnROS/plan",Path,callback)
rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394885/how-to-get-length-of-array-if-poses-from-nav_msgs/path.msg/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks guys! I typed `pose` instead of `poses`, that messed me up. Its fixed now, its `len(msg.poses)`

---

Originally posted by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) with karma: 167 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Shouldn't it be rather `print("list: ", msg.data)` in your callback? Check ROS documentation [there](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node) for correct form of ROS1 subscriber. The array `poses` can be acquired as the field of `msg.data`.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2022-01-23**:
You can access the whole Path with `msg.data` and the pose list with `msg.data.pose`. To get the length, you would need to use `print("list: ", len(msg.data.poses))`.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-24**:
@ljaniec when I used `msg.data` it gave an error about `Path` not having attribute `data` or something like that.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-24**:
@ljaniec I figured it out thanks!